# Transfor XML to SOAP and select few elements instead of all

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I have a requirement where I need to transfrom an XML message to a soap message. Here is the input I am getting as part of a request:

```
<response status="200">
    <CustomField>
        <CustomList>
            <List>123</List>
            <StatusList>four</StatusList>
            <ErrorMessage>failed</ErrorMessage>
        </CustomList>
        <CustomList>
            <List>acv</List>
            <StatusList>three</StatusList>
            <ErrorMessage>failed</ErrorMessage>
        </CustomList>
    </CustomField>
</response>
```

The intented output is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <wsdl:statusResponse xmlns:wsdl="http://ee.co.uk/status/wsdl">
            <output>
                <Listentifier>
                            <customList>
                                <list>123</list>
                                <statusList>four</statusList>
                            </customList>
                            <customList>
                                <list>acv</list>
                                <statusList>three</statusList>
                            </customList>
                </Listentifier>
            </output>
        </wsdl:statusResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I tried using the below XSL, which gives me all the element from the input, but I need few selected elements to be added in my output. How can I do that?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:wsdl="http://ee.co.uk/status/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>    
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:if test="/response/CustomField/CustomList/List">
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
                <soap:Header/>
                <soap:Body>

                    <wsdl:statusResponse>
                        <output>
                            <Listentifier>
                                <xsl:apply-templates/>
                            </Listentifier>
                        </output>
                    </wsdl:statusResponse>
                </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="List">
        <list>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </list>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="StatusList">
        <statusList>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </statusList>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: XML is case-sensitive; do you really want to have one `customList` and one `CustomList`?

Comment: Both are customList, it was a typo. Updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/response">
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <soap:Header/>
        <soap:Body>
            <wsdl:statusResponse xmlns:wsdl="http://ee.co.uk/status/wsdl">
                <output>
                    <Listentifier>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>      
                    </Listentifier>
                </output>
            </wsdl:statusResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CustomList">
    <customList>
        <list>
            <xsl:value-of select="List"/>
        </list>
        <statusList>
            <xsl:value-of select="StatusList"/>
        </statusList>
    </customList>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```